# display total count of records in per user

Tags: php, mysql

```
$u=$_POST['userid'];

$sql=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(username) AS total FROM TABLENAME where username=$u");
```

This query only retun the total records for `username=$u`

I want all users records to be displayed in total

I want something likes

```
User           Records
User1            1152
user2            2365
user3            2365 
------            -------
userN           XXX
```

I am using php and mysql.

Also please tell. What shall I echo, `$sql` or `Total`?

Thanks for your help

I tried this : and receiving error on line :

```
while($fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
```

This is code that you guys gave me

'; print_r($array);


    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>

Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `GROUP BY`

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT username, COUNT(username) AS total 
                          FROM TABLENAME GROUP BY username");

$array = array();
while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
    $array[$fetch['username']] = $fetch['total'];
}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($array);
```

`$array` will give you what you want.

Comment: Error on line : Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in C:\wamp\www\xxx.php on line 21
Line 21: while($fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))

Comment: I'm sorry. There was a typo. Kindly use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysql_fetch_assoc()`

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, per user:

```
SELECT COUNT(username) AS total FROM TABLENAME GROUP BY username
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT COUNT(username) AS total FROM TABLENAME GROUP BY username`

If you want to see which user it is as well, just add it to the SELECT:

```
SELECT username, COUNT(username) AS total FROM TABLENAME GROUP BY username
```

^As described in the question, that should do.

To display the results:

```
$u=$_POST['userid'];

$sql=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(username) AS total FROM TABLENAME where username=$u");

while ($user = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
    echo($user["username"] . ": " . $user["total"]);
}
```